# swift import a class is not identified

Tags: ios, swift

I added a class

```
import UIKit

class Mean{

}
```

and I have another class

```
import UIKit


class MealTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: Properties
    var meals = [Meal]()

}
```

I am getting this error:

> `used of unresolved identified Meal`

I am working with swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your class name is `Mean`...its typo.. so change this line

```
var meals = [Meal]()
```

to

```
var meals = [Mean]()
```

Or change class name to `Meal` instead of `Mean`

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a typo: `Mean != Meal`